# Writing a class inside a function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a class inside a function... something like the following:

```
def func(**args):
   class BindArgs(object):
       foo = args['foo']
       print 'foo is ', foo
       def __init__(self,args):
          print " hello, I am here"

f = func(foo=2)
```

I was hoping that print will be executed.. but the **init** block is not being executed... though print 'foo is ' stub runs... What am I missing?

I am trying to understand, how does this module works (https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/binder.py)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return an instance of the class...

```
def func(**args):
   class BindArgs(object):
       foo = args['foo']
       print 'foo is ', foo
       def __init__(self,args):
          print " hello i am here"
   return BindArgs(args) #return an instance of the class

f = func(foo=3)
```

If you wanted to call it later like in the example from the comments, you could just do

```
def func(**args):
   class BindArgs(object):
       foo = args['foo']
       print 'foo is ', foo
       def __init__(self,args):
          print " hello i am here"
   return BindArgs

f = func(foo=3)
f(args="yellow")
```

Comment: So, how does this works (https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/binder.py)

Comment: im guessing with the `_call` method that is returned at the end ... but who knows Im not sure how thats invoked or used so I couldnt tell you

Comment: as expected `user_point=bind_api(**kwargs); user_point()` they call the binding later ... since bind_api returns a method call ...

Comment: Where is the above line of code.. is it in api.py file

Comment: thats how you invoke the api_bind point that you create ... im not sure where in the code that happens... and dont want to dig but thats how you invoke it ... if you edit that file and add print statements to `__init__` you will see it does not invoke until you call the returned method ... which is exactly what you would expect

Answer (score 0):

Inside `func` you're not actually initializing a new `BindArgs` object, so Python will not call the `__init__()` function.  However, it does read through the class definition to use it inside the function scope, so it *does* execute the other *print* statement...

Answer (score 0):

That's because **init** is only executed when an instance of the class is being created, which is not happening in your function. You have to explicitly call `BindArgs(someobject)` for that. However, the class is being defined when you call `func`, so the contents of the class definition are executed.