# SQLAlchemy: __tablename__ as a variable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a prototype to pull stocks ticks and dump them to a DB. I want to pass `__tablename__` as a parameter to SQLAchemy so that stock ticks for a given stocks gets written down to its own table. (BTW, I am new to SQLAlchemy)

I referred this thread: [Python Sqlalchemy - tablename as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728779/python-sqlalchemy-tablename-as-a-variable)

And came up with below code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Date


Base = declarative_base()


def create_models(tablename):

    class Stock(Base):

        __tablename__ = tablename

        timestamp = Column(String, primary_key=True)
        ltp = Column(String)

        def __init__(self, timestamp, ltp):
            self.timestamp = timestamp
            self.ltp = ltp

create_models('ABCD')

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////ticks.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)()

tick = Stock('2019-02-12 09:15:00', '287')
Session.merge(tick)
Session.commit()
```

But it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickies.py", line 32, in <module>
    tick = Stock('2019-02-12 09:15:00', '287')
NameError: name 'Stock' is not defined
```

The error is quite obvious. But then I am unsure how to proceed with `__tablename__` as a variable. Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: Does the table exist already?

Comment: No. I believe `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` this line is creating the table. If I remove the `create_models` function and run the code by hardcoding `__tablename__`, the code works fine. It creates table on 1st run and on subsequent runs, it continues to inserts the records.

Comment: take `class Stock` out side of function `create_models`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, If I take `class Stock` out side of `create_models`, then how do I pass `__tablename__` as a variable.

Comment: that return your class from the function and use that for further operation

Comment: The class is local to the function's scope. Return it, if you want to use it outside. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520435/writing-a-class-inside-a-function-in-python

Comment: use `return Stock` in your function and then `Stock = create_models('ABCD')` then `tick = Stock('2019-02-12 09:15:00', '287')`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, Superb!!! Thanks a lot. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer added :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scope of your `Stock` class limited to `create_models` function. To create object of this class outside the function you can return the class from the function and then use it.

have a look on below solution:

```
def create_models(tablename):

    class Stock(Base):

        __tablename__ = tablename

        timestamp = Column(String, primary_key=True)
        ltp = Column(String)

        def __init__(self, timestamp, ltp):
            self.timestamp = timestamp
            self.ltp = ltp
    return Stock #return the class 

Stock = create_models('ABCD')
tick = Stock('2019-02-12 09:15:00', '287')
```

have a look at [Python scope tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespaces-and-scope-in-python/) for more detail related to scope.