# Do you still need to create SQLAlchemy models if the DB already exists?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

**New to Flask and SQL - teaching myself to build a fairly basic web app.**

The lessons that I have followed so far haven't made it clear to me how a pre-existing SQLite database interacts with SQLAlchemy.

I have created an SQLite database using SQL in my terminal which already has the tables set up that I want to use.

I am *now* looking to connect it to my Flask app using SQLAlchemy. For examples sake lets say this is the model of a Book table in my DB has the following SQL setup:

```
CREATE TABLE "Book" (
    "isbn"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "author"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```

Is the purpose of outlining the model in the Flask app like below just so that the application knows how to interact with the DB?

```
class Book(db.Model):
    isbn = db.column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.column(db.String(50), unique = False, index = True)
    author = db.column(db.String(50), unique = True, index = True)
```

And given the double up in almost all of the information that is presented - is there a more efficient way to import a model like this from a database that is already set up?

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique called [reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#orm-declarative-reflected) to generate declarative SQLAlchemy classes based on existing tables in your DB.

For example:

```py
"""Example of table reflection with SQLAlchemy"""
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Session

# Create a SQLAlchemy engine connected to an in-memory SQLite3 DB:
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

# Create the table in the DB using DDL:
DDL = text(
    """
    CREATE TABLE Book (
        "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        isbn TEXT NOT NULL,
        title TEXT NOT NULL,
        author TEXT NOY NULL
    );
    """
)
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(DDL)

# Confirm table is empty:
select_all = text("SELECT * FROM Book;")
with Session(engine) as session:
    print(session.execute(select_all).fetchall())
    # []


# Use reflection to automatically generate a SQLAlchemy Book model:
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Book(Base):
    __table__ = Table("Book", Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)


# Insert a new book using the reflected table:
the_hobbit = Book(
    isbn="9780007270613",
    title="The Hobbit",
    author="J. R. R. Tolkien"
)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(the_hobbit)
    session.flush()
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    print(session.execute(select_all).one())
    # [(1, '9780007270613', 'The Hobbit', 'J. R. R. Tolkien')]
```

The key part is the use of `autoload_with=engine` the `Book` python class definition.

This example was tested with `Python 3.10` and `SQLAlchemy 2.0`, but you can do the same with other versions, and with the Flask-Sqlalchemy plugin.

You can also look at more advanced usage such as deferred reflection and automap.

Answer (score -1):

You add new line tablename, old topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646044/sqlalchemy-tablename-as-a-variable/54646796)
[Document](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html)

```
class Book(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'Book'
    isbn = db.column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.column(db.String(50), unique = False, index = True)
    author = db.column(db.String(50), unique = True, index = True)
```

Comment: He's asking for a way to access the already existing dB without having to create models in flask.